# Google Custom Search, how to run by querystring value?

Tags: asp.net, google-search

Hey I have signed up for the google custom search and its working reasonably well.

So basically it generated a Javascript code for me to use.

I was wondering how can I get it to work by also accepting a value from querystring ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the following vb.net code to achieve this:

```
google.load('search', '1', { language: 'en' });
google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
        var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('[your se code here]');
        customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
        customSearchControl.draw('cse');
        customSearchControl.execute('<%=server.htmlencode(request.querystring("searchterm"))%>');
     }, true);
```